# How to add style relevant to class name to element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I'm ready to make a tool to improve my work. Please look at the code.

```html
<div class="container width-200"></div>
<div class="container width-300"></div>
```

I want to set the first div width to `200px` and second to `300px` using jquery dynamicaly.
I don't know how to handle it in Javascript.

How can i do this work?

Comment: why not have a class named width-300 and set the width property to 300px inside that class.

Comment: Do you want to set `width: 300px` to element has class `width-300` using javascript?

Comment: @heekei using what you want to assign width:300px you have used 4 tags html,css,js or jquery.

Comment: @fmt em,because I think it covers  these four tags.. I don't know whether something is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find element has class `width-*` that `*` should be only digit. You can use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check class name. If class name is right, add digit of class to width of element.

```js
$("[class*=width-]").each(function(){
    var match = $(this).attr("class").match(/width-([\d]+)/);
    if (match)
        $(this).css("width", match[1]);
});
```

```css
div {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width-100">100</div>
<div class="width-200">200</div>
<div class="width-300">300</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use custom attributes.

> HTML 5 explicitly allows custom attributes that begin with data. So, for example, `<p data-date-changed="Jan 24 5:23 p.m.">Hello</p>` is valid. Since it's officially supported by a standard, I think this is the best option for custom attributes. And it doesn't require you to overload other attributes with hacks, so your HTML can stay semantic.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Please use below in js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.width-300').css({'width':'300px','border':'1px solid #000' });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container width-300">
  Width 300
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container
{
  margin:0 auto;
}

.width-300
{
  width: 300px;
}
```